# How do I get data type of property in a class through Reflection C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I have a namespace called `MyNamespace.Demo1`, one static class called `STClass` and one property inside that class called `prpAssm`. How do I get the data-type of property `prpAssm`?

Answer (score 3):

```
Type classType = typeof(STClass);
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = classType.GetProperty("prpAssm");
Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
```

if the class is in another project you should load the assembly.

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"MyNamespace.Demo1.dll");
Type classType = assembly.GetType("MyNamespace.Demo1.STClass");
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = classType.GetProperty("prpAssm");
Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
```

BR

Comment: How would I do if the name of the class is dynamic? @ Matthias

Comment: `Type classType = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.Demo1.STClass");` but why would you want sthg like that

Comment: Yes. But when I do so am getting null @Matthias

Comment: is your class in another project? then you should load the assembly. use `Assembly.LoadFrom(...)` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile`
eg  
  
`var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"MyNamespace.Demo1.dll");  
Type classType = assembly.GetType("MyNamespace.Demo1.STClass");  
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = classType.GetProperty("prpAssm");  
Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;`

Comment: Anyway, could you maybe describe more what you want to achieve and why. there could be better ways achieving what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:- (Use [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
Assembly myAss = Assembly.LoadFile(@"YourAssemblyPath.dll");
Type myType = myAss.GetType("MyNamespace.Demo1.STClass");
PropertyInfo myProp = myType.GetProperty("prpAssm");
Console.WriteLine(myProp.PropertyType);
```

Comment: myType is getting null. Is that because the code for the class is encrypted? @ Rahul Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu - I don't think so..Your code might be encrypted but not the Type definition right? Can you show the code you are trying..?

Comment: Actually I am calling my form from a parent form, which is a paid version. We can only access the values of their properties and cannot view the code. 
I can't paste the code because of security issues @ Rahul Singh

Comment: @SarathAvanavu - I am not asking for client code, I asked how you are trying to fetch! Have you loaded the `assembly` first? Please check my Edit. In `LoadFile` you need to specify your full assemply path and name.

Comment: I have already added the dll. I am able to get some of the class's properties (some classes are exposed to us by default), but cannot access the others(except the values from that properties) @ Rahul Singh